# how not to escape characters using fwrite in php

Tags: php, json, escaping

I facing a problem with fwrite here. I am getting some  json result in the form `"sometextbefore\"&amp;sometextafter"`

Notice that I am getting a **backslash** before the **"**, But when I am using fwrite to write this content onto a file, it is something like this.

`"sometextbefore"&amp;sometextafter"`

I don't know why the **backslash** is being ignored, I want to write to my file whatever I have received as the json response.

Please help, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape it twice :

```
"sometextbefore\\\"&amp;sometextafter"
```